# How to create a mock view controller from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, storyboard, xctest

I'm trying to create a mock view controller for a view controller that was created from a storyboard.

If I try to downcast it as following, it doesn't work since the storyboard view controller is encoded:

```swift
let _storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = _storyboard.instantiateViewController(ofType: ViewController.self) as? MockViewController
```

where `MockViewController` is the subclass of `ViewController`.

I tried initializing the mock view controller using the nib name, but the nil error happens for the uninitialized `@IBOutlet` properties:

```swift
class MockViewController: ViewController {
    init() {
        let controllerName = String(describing: ViewController.self)
        super.init(nibName: controllerName, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I could potentially create an identical view controller and initialize them manually:

```swift
let _storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = _storyboard.instantiateViewController(ofType: ViewController.self)
let mockViewController = MockViewController()
mockViewController.someProperty = vc.property
```

but doesn't seem very efficient and also it entails always manually coordinating changes in both the production code and the test code.

The most promising method I found was using this [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboard/3213989-instantiateviewcontroller):

```swift
let controllerName = String(describing: ViewController.self)
let mockVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: controllerName, creator: { coder -> MockViewController? in
    return MockViewController(coder: coder)
})
```

where the `MockViewController` is the subclass of `ViewController` again and has the following initializer:

```swift
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

However, this also results in the same error as the first one where the `@IBOutlet` properties return nil errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "mock"? That is, what role will it play in a test case? And do you want it from a storyboard or from a XIB?

Comment: I agree with that question. You obviously wouldn't mock the view controller in order to test the view controller; to test the view controller you'd mock everything _else_. So what exactly is the point here?

Comment: I'm getting it from a storyboard. I'm mocking the view controller not because of the visual components, but because the codebase uses the VIPER architecture and in order to test the elements like the presenter, interacter, I need to frequently capture values being passed to view controllers from these elements. For example, when a presenter calls `view?.setMap(center: location, direction: direction, altitude: 2000)` where view is the view controller, I'd like to use a mock view controller to capture the parameters within the `setMap` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use "Subclass and Override" to do partial mocking, so that you can record calls to the view controller. But this isn't possible on a view controller defined in a storyboard. As I write in my book,

> Storyboard-based view controller can't be subclassed because the storyboard stores an instance of a predetermined type.

Alternatives:

- Load your storyboard from a XIB instead of a Storyboard.
- Define your UI programatically instead of in a Storyboard.
- Have your Presenter use a protocol instead of a direct reference to your view controller. Then inject what you like using property injection.